Calculate differential $dF_j$ of $F:j\mapsto j^2+I$ on $O(n)$
Given the map $F:j\mapsto j^2+I$ on the orthogonal group $O(n)$, what is the differential $dF_j$ ?  How do I calculate this?
I am trying to understand Example 7 in Lecture Notes on Symmetric Spaces by J.-H. Eschenburg. Thank you for helping me!

A few misunderstandings here. Looking at the actual example in the linked notes, the manifold you want is actually $S=O(n)\cap A(n)$, the set of matrices which are both orthogonal and anti-symmetric. Even then, $F$ as you've written is not a map on $S$ (or $O(n)$). Here, $F$ is simply the defining map of the manifold $S$, i.e., $S = F^{-1}(0)$. This is just a map from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to itself, so you can easily take the gradient.

@EuYu Thank you for your helpful, understanding comment and for taking a look at Eschenburg.  I will take the gradient. But I am still wondering how do I do that in this example?

@EuYu when you say "just a map from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ to itself", how does that account for matrix multiplication? I assume that $j^2$ means squaring the matrix but not a vector.
